# Pass a variable when using pug extends

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a settings page called `posting.pug` and it `extends` a pug `settingsLayout` template. 
Where are several settings pages in my app. And I want to pass a variable  `posting=1` to the `settingsLayout` page to show a user that the posting page is the current.

How should I pass a variable to the template I extend?

I tried to set a variable before `extends`. That's not allowed.

I tried passing it as an attribute -- doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try like this

**settingsLayout.pug**

```
block variables    

doctype html
html
  head
  body
    // Try to call variable here
    h1 posting
```

**posting.pug**

```
extends settingsLayout

block variables
  - var posting = 1
```

I hope this work!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing which does not work is overriding pug variables in included files.
>   It works well with
>   `php compiler pug-php/pug@^3.4`
>   but does not work with
>   `webpack pug-loader@^2.4.0 pug@^2.0.4 webpack@^4.43.0 webpack-dev-server@^3.11.0`.

I have a more complicated version.
I would like to override a lot of variables, for instance I have pageTitle, siteTitle, siteDivider variables.

I have a homepage which is `views/index.pug`.
I have a layout which is `views/layouts/default.pug`.
I have default variables stored in a few files: `views/vars/page.pug`, `views/vars/site.pug`.

Let's start with variables:

File `views/vars/page.pug`

```
- var pageTitle = "##Default##"
```

File `views/vars/site.pug`

```
- var siteTitle = "Yaro"
- var siteDivider = "|"
```

File `views/index.pug`

```
extend layouts/default

block vars
  include vars/site
  include vars/page
  - var pageTitle = "Business Solutions & IT development"
```

File `views/layouts/default.pug`

```
block vars
  include ../vars/site
  include ../vars/page

doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no")
    title #{pageTitle} #{siteDivider} #{siteTitle}
  body
    block body
```

So I wait for the result in the title: Business Solutions & IT development | Yaro

But I receive only: Business Solutions & IT development
without siteDivider and siteTitle :(

But if I have a file like this `views/index.pug`

```
extend layouts/default

block vars
  include vars/site
  include vars/page
  - var pageTitle = "Business Solutions & IT development"
  - var siteDivider = "|"
  - var siteTitle = "Yaro"
```

It works just fine.

My point is to use default variables to override only needed but not all.